# Limit for $x$ raised to a negative.

Tags: graphing-functions, exponentiation

Messing around with a graphing calculator, I noticed that after I raised $f(x) = x$ to some large negative number, the two vertical lines stretching from $-1$ and $1$ stopped. I have a few questions:

How do I find out at exactly what point this happens?

Why does this happen?

Is it just a rounding error or something in the graphing calculator that makes this occur?

I would appreciate any answers or leads.

Comment: Which "large negative number" did you raise $x$ to?

Comment: I tried a lot, and it seemed to be somewhere around -10000000000000000000

Comment: What was the scaling?

Comment: Partial disappearance reproduced at default scaling for $x^a$ where $a=-4 \times 10^{18}$. Total disappearance reproduced at $a=-8 \times 10^{18}$.

Comment: It is unlikely that people know the algorithm of desmos.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I find out at exactly what point this happens?

It happens when k tends to infinity, just look at the chart of an exponential function. If the base is more then one then it tends to 0 for x that tends to minus infinity. Else if the base is less then one then it tends to infinity.

Maybe it is more clear like this:
$$a > 1 \to \lim_{x\to -\infty} a^x = 0$$
$$a < 1 \to \lim_{x\to -\infty} a^x = \infty$$
While:
$$\lim_{x\to -\infty} 1^x = 1$$

> Why does this happen?

This is also the interpretation of the chart.

> Is it just a rounding error or something in the graphing calculator that makes this occur?

Exactly.. look for example at the following pictures (they are taken from google online chart, just type your function on google search bar).

[plot of f(x) = x^(0-1000000)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aC0A.png)

Just by zooming a bit:

[you see that it is an approximation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Nzng.png)

Comment: Thank you very much. Would these be considered asymptotes?

Comment: There is only one vertical asymptote, in 0, not in 1 or -1. Notice that you can write the function as f(x) = 1/x^k, so in 0 it is not defined and it has an asymptote.